# Series expansion of $(x - 1)^{-1}$ about infinity

Tags: complex-integration, laurent-series

I am trying to expand the function $f(x) = \left( x - 1 \right)^{-1}$ about a large value of $x$. I believe I need to use a Laurent series to accomplish this. I am not familiar with complex analysis, however, and I don't know how to begin.

I know that the Laurent series is defined as $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n \left( z - z_0 \right)^n$ with $a_n = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint\limits_C \frac{f(z')dz'}{(z'-z_0)^{n+1}}$. I do not, however, know how to define a contour $C$ at infinity (wouldn't $z_0$ be infinite?). I also do not know how to evaluate the integral over said contour (residue theorem?).

WolframAlpha says that the expansion about infinity is $\sum\limits_{n>0}x^{-n}$. It does not, however, provide any steps or the reasoning behind this. How is this result achieved?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $\dfrac1{x-1}=\dfrac{\frac1x}{1-\frac1x}=\frac1x\left(1+\frac1x+\cdots\right)$

Comment: You can always try setting $y=\frac 1x$ and expanding in terms of $y$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** if $|x|>1$,

$$\frac{1}{x-1} = \frac{1}{x} \times \frac{1}{1- \frac{1}{x}} = \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^n} $$